# Why is jquery only registering a click once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know it's got to be a stupid simple problem, but it's been holding my back for too long...

I want to click the menu icon (picture) in the top right corner and have it display a transparent div menu over the entire screen. Then when I click the icon again, I want it to disappear.

JQuery is supposed to be hiding and showing a div on each click of the button. It shows the div the first time but after that, it doesn't register the click. I'm using transparent divs quite a lot on this project so my first guess is that something loads that is covering the button and that is stopping the click from "reaching" the button in question. But I've set a z-index to the button so it appears above everything else (also corroborated by the background color property) and yet when I click the button a second time, the div that it is supposed to hide stays there.

Here's my JQuery code:

```
$("#menuButton").click(function(){
    if($("#menuOverlay").hasClass("displayIt")){
        $("#menuOverlay").fadeOut(400);
    } else {
        $("#menuOverlay").fadeIn(400);
    }
});
```

And here's my HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <header>
            <p class="homeLink">Company Name Here</p>
            <div id="menuButton"><img class="menuIcon" src="images/menuIcon.png"/></div>
        </header>
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="sliderPic"></div>
            <div class="sliderText"><p>This is come content just chilling right here.</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div id="arrowJumper"><img class="arrowIcon" src="images/greyArrow.png"/></div>
    </footer>
    <div id="menuOverlay" class="menuDiv">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li>Work.</li>
            <li>About.</li>
            <li>Careers.</li>
            <li>Ideas.</li>
            <li>News.</li>
            <li>Events.</li>
            <li>Contact.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
```

And just in case it's relevant, here's my CSS:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body, html, .non-footer {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.footer {
    height: 55px;
    margin-top: -55px;
    width: 100%;
}

#arrowJumper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 55px;
    margin-top: -56px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    /*background-image: url('../images/greyArrow.png'); 
    background-position: center -15px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
}

header {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 90;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    z-index: 90;
}

.slider {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
    display: block;
    background: blue;
}

.homeLink {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    color: #ff6633;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 26px;
}

#menuButton {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#arrowJumper img{

-webkit-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.920, 0.065, 0.365, 0.570); 
   -moz-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.920, 0.065, 0.365, 0.570); 
     -o-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.920, 0.065, 0.365, 0.570); 
        transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.920, 0.065, 0.365, 0.570); /* custom */
    margin-top: -15px;
}

#arrowJumper:hover {
    background-color: #ff6633;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 600ms linear;
       -moz-transition: background-color 600ms linear;
         -o-transition: background-color 600ms linear;
        -ms-transition: background-color 600ms linear;
            transition: background-color 600ms linear;
}

#arrowJumper:hover img {
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.920, 0.065, 0.365, 0.570); 
       -moz-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.920, 0.065, 0.365, 0.570); 
         -o-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.920, 0.065, 0.365, 0.570); 
            transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.920, 0.065, 0.365, 0.570); /* custom */

    margin-top: 4px;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#menuOverlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#menuOverlay {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;
    background: rgb(200, 102, 51); /* The Fallback */
    background: rgba(200, 102, 51, 0.5);
    text-align: center;
    height: 960px;
}

#menuOverlay ul{
    vertical-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 56px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #fff;
}

#menuOverlay ul li{
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 0.25em;
    padding-bottom: 0.25em;
}

#menuOverlay ul li:hover{
    color: #ff6633;
    background: #fff;
}

.displayIt {
    display: block;
}
```

And here's a fiddle for convenience: http://jsfiddle.net/yv9mr/
I'm pretty new at all of this so I really appreciate your assistance. I'm sure it's something simple. Thanks all!

Comment: You can't click on an element that is behind another one. Once the menuOverlay is visible, it is covering the menuButton.

Comment: It is NOT registered once.  Your overlay is covering up the button.

Comment: Or maybe you never change the class, so `displayIt` is either always there, or never there and the condition always evaluates to the same value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add/remove class on each click like this in your `if-else` block

```
 if($("#menuOverlay").hasClass("displayIt")){
        $("#menuOverlay").fadeOut(400);
            $("#menuOverlay").removeClass("displayIt"); //remove class
    } else {
        $("#menuOverlay").fadeIn(400);
        $("#menuOverlay").addClass("displayIt"); //add  class
    }
```

But the simplest way would be to [fadeToggle](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) the required div , in order to hide/show:

```
$("#menuOverlay").fadeToggle();
```

Comment: Thanks! I used your answer but everybody pretty much agreed with you so I've given everyone upvotes. Thanks guys! I appreciate it! Problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use jQuerys `.fadeToggle()` method. In my opinion cleaner to let jQuery manage the toggle effect:

```
$("#menuButton").click(function(){
    $("#menuOverlay").fadeToggle(400);
});
```

Tested and works with your example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WArtL/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var clicked = false;
$("#menuButton").click(function(){
if (clicked == true){
    $("#menuOverlay").fadeOut(400);
    clicked = false;
} else {
    $("#menuOverlay").fadeIn(400);
    clicked = true;
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are not adding or removing the class. Your event listener is working correctly, but you should add

```
$("#menuOverlay").toggleClass("displayIt");
```

to the end of your javascript (after the `if`/`else`).

A class such as "expanded" would be more semantic.

Answer (score 1):

**Reason** Function is called again but your condition `if($("#menuOverlay").hasClass("displayIt"))` is always true so else never executes.. You can do

```
$("#menuButton").click(function(){    
    if($("#menuOverlay").hasClass("displayIt")){
        $("#menuOverlay").removeClass("displayIt");
        $("#menuOverlay").fadeOut(400);
    } else {
    $("#menuOverlay").addClass("displayIt");
        $("#menuOverlay").fadeIn(400);
    }
});
```

#### Fiddle

Or Simply

```
var shown=false;
$("#menuButton").click(function(){    
if(!shown)
{
    $("#menuOverlay").fadeOut(400);
    shown =true;
}
else
{
    $("#menuOverlay").fadeIn(400);
    shown=false;
}
});
```

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you! Since the others commented first, I chose one of their answers as the best answer instead. But thank you very much for your input!